# some videos have sound and some have no sound on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, sound

I am facing a strange issue. I can heard audio from youtube and other downloaded video files from my ubuntu. I have bought some courses from udemy. Surprisingly, there is no audio when I play those videos on my browser. I have changed the browser but no help. I even downloaded the video to my pc and play from that. Video is running but there is no audio! I don't understand what's the problem as other videos is running with audio.

This is the property of the video from where I am NOT getting any sound.

[image]

And This is the property of the video from where I am getting sound.

[image]

Note: videos from udemy is running correctly (with audio) at windows 10 in my other pc.

============== **Update** ===================

I found the problem! Cable of my headphone is so small that can't reach to my ear if I directly insert it at speaker port. That's why, I use an extension cable. But, with the cable I can't hear audio from udemy's video. Without cable, I can hear it. But, it's still strange as I can hear audio from other video's (except udemy's videos) with the extension cable! Any solution for it without changing the cable?

[image]

Comment: Please provide list of tested browsers.

Comment: @S_Flash, I've tested on chrome and firefox. This is not issue with browsers. Because, I downloaded the video files on my pc (Ubuntu) and I am not getting any sound from those files. But, those video is playing with audio on my other windows pc

Comment: Try install run in command line: `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras`

Answer (score 0):

To install all media codecs for Ubuntu run in (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra
```

If you need play videos on desktop only, you can install **VLC media player** from **Ubuntu Software** (VLC has own codecs).

Comment: I have run this, still the issue exist. the download flies from udemy is mp4. I run it with vlc too. But, there is no audio. Other mp4 is running with audio in my ubuntu.

Comment: I found the problem. Can you please read the Update portion of my post?